# Python + SQL: Как получить чистое значение из запроса

Tags: python, postgresql

```
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                      # пароль, который указали при установке PostgreSQL
                                      password="********",
                                      host="127.0.0.1",
                                      port="5432",
                                      database="postgres")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute('select max(id) from zavod_1_92_25')
        n = cursor.fetchone()
        print(n)
```

Вывод :

```
(3,)
```

Как получить просто 3 без нудного удаления скобочек.

Comment: `max_id = n[0]` ?

Comment: @MaxU может автор вопроса считает это нудным удалением)))

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, оно самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот так

```
n=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```